# WPF ItemsControl not binding when I change an item property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
<ItemsControl Margin="0,16" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8,0,8,18">
                    <Image Height="6" Source="MultiSelectorTick.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="4"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=selectionConverter}}" 
                        Text="{Binding DisplayName, FallbackValue=Not Specified}" Margin="4,0,0,0" FontSize="13.333" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <MC_Windows:ExecuteCommandAction TargetCommand="ToggleExecuted"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

datasource of an ObservableCollection where filter is defined here:

```
private ICommand toggleExecuted;
    public ICommand ToggleExecuted
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.toggleExecuted == null)
                this.toggleExecuted = new RelayCommand(
                    e => { this.IsSelected = !this.IsSelected; });
            return toggleExecuted;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return this.isSelected; }
        set
        {
            this.isSelected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

When the mouseleftdown event fires it calls the command (which works I set a breakpoint). As you can see it is updating the IsSelected state. However, the interface doesn't appear to be updating.

Comment: Is the selectionConverter working? Can you setup breakpoint in that converter?

Comment: It converter is working because the display updates with different colors based on whether or not the item is marked as IsSelected when the collection is originally populated.

Comment: The converter is never called when you click on the item though. Which says the binding only seems to work when the collection is first populated.

Comment: If I add this.DisplayName = "Test"; to the ICommand the interface doesn't update the DisplayName either even though the property is being set correctly and the INotifyPropertyChanged event is being fired on the Filter Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the execution into the base control and it worked.